# I have two values in href and I want to use both values one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two values in href and I want to use both values one by one. Can 
anyone help me how I do this? Below I put my code which I tried. It's working in first step. That means the value is set when I click first time but the value is not set when I clicked on same element the second time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var sliptLink = link.split(',');
    var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
    var secondLink = sliptLink[1];
    /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[1]);
      console.log(sliptLink[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent first">
  <a href="#123,#321">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#456,#654">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#789,#987">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is replacing the href with first click, so removing the second entry - consider using a different attribute, like data-href

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var sliptLink = link.split(',');
    var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
    var secondLink = sliptLink[1];
    /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[1]);
      console.log(sliptLink[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* added for display */
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent first">
  <a data-href="#123,#321">Link 1</a>
  <a data-href="#456,#654">Link 3</a>
  <a data-href="#789,#987">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, iwant to set the value of sliptLink[0] when parent hasclass first, and if parent has not class first it will set the value from sliptLink[1].when i click same element second time it gives me undefiend

Comment: Try the code snippet in the answer, it works as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Change your links to `<a href="#" data-href="#789,#987">Link 2</a>` and then use `$(this).attr('data-href')`.

Problem was that when you updated `.attr('href', sliptLink[0])` it would remove the second `#123` from the original `href`

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var link = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var sliptLink = link.split(',');
    var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
    var secondLink = sliptLink[1];
    /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[1]);
      console.log(sliptLink[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="parent first">
  <a href="#" data-href="#123,#321">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-href="#456,#654">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-href="#789,#987">Link 2</a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, because the second time, your `href` has only one value, that too without comma

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
      var sliptLink = link.split(',');
      var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('href', link);
      console.log(link);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent first">
  <a href="#123,#321">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#456,#654">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#789,#987">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your first click just set `href` to `sliptLink[0]`**.

So that the 2nd click won't know what `sliptLink[1]` is.

This could be done with a separated data-attribute (E.g: `data-link`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('data-link');
    var sliptLink = link.split(',');
    var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
    var secondLink = sliptLink[1];
    /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[1]);
      console.log(sliptLink[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent first">
  <a href="#123,#321" data-link="#123,#321">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#456,#654" data-link="#456,#654">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#789,#987" data-link="#789,#987">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  just Declare Global Variable;

  var glink=null;
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.parent a').click(function () {
           if(glink==null)
            glink = $(this).attr('href');
           var sliptLink = glink.split(',');
           var firstLink = sliptLink[0];
           var secondLink = sliptLink[1];
           /* this code execute when parent has class first  */
           if ($(this).parent().hasClass('first')) {
               $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[0]);
               $(this).parent().removeClass('first');
           } else {
               $(this).attr('href', sliptLink[1]);
               $(this).parent().addClass('first');
               console.log(sliptLink[1]);
           }
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Vanilla JS**

```
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.parent a')).forEach((e) => {
        e.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var links = e.hash.split(',');
            console.log(links);
        })
    });
```